# Function call misunderstanding

Tags: c

For example, I have a recursive function which calculate n!.

```
 int fact(int n){
    if(n==1)
       return 1;
    return n*fact(n-1);
}
```

My question is why I can't replace n-1 with n--? Or can I replace it with --n?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: `n` is used twice in the return expression, careful with order of evaluation guarantees...

Comment: please pick a language : C++ != C (especially if you get into the nooks and crannies like sequencing)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: There is a difference between n-1 and --n in this code. You will get incorrect result with --n.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because it changes the value of `n`. Since the value is used to compute the expression `n * fact(...)`, the value of `n` must be read *after* the `fact` is evaluated. Since `--n` (or `n--`, it does not matter here) must be passed as value to `fact`, the decrement must occur *before* the `fact` is invoked. Therefore the expression result will be incorrect.

Comment: I would rather say "can be incorrect", there is also a chance that it will evaluate as the OP expects (with `--n` at least)

Comment: It depends what value you pass to fact in case of --n. For 0, it will crash, for 1 it will be correct. And then it will be incorrect.

Comment: It doesn't have to crash, since a tail recursion could be optimized to an iteration

Comment: @JamesBond And it would yield correct results if n is evaluated, then decremented and finally fed to funct, which would be perfectly possible afaics

Comment: Comments are correct, but I think OP's  question is at a more superficial understanding level.

Comment: @RemusRusanu Maybe, but this Q/A is not only for the OP, but for all interested readers

Answer (score 4):

There are two reasons.

One, `n--` is post-decrement. The value used as the arugment would be the original (non-decremented) value of `n`.

Two, `n` is used twice in the expression (once as the left-hand side argument of `*`, and once within the argument to the recursive call). Neither C nor C++ specify evaluation order in this case, so it would be unclear whether the `n` is evaluated before or after `n--` (or even `--n`).